# Which Ruby does Vim use for :ruby commands?

Tags: ruby, vim, rubygems

Vim has support for Ruby commands.  (For more information, please see  [the `:help if-ruby` documentation](https://vimhelp.org/if_ruby.txt.html#Ruby).)  These commands can be run using `:ruby` if `+ruby` support is enabled (see `vim --version`).  As an example, I can see that I'm currently using v3.0.0 by using:

```
:ruby print RUBY_VERSION
```

However, which Ruby installation is this?  For example, is it system Ruby, something managed by RVM, or a ​separate Ruby installation that is built into Vim?

Also, is it possible to install Ruby gems to use with `:ruby` commands?

---

Details about my installation:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.7
BuildVersion:   19H524
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Mar 21 2021 06:59:54)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-2625
Compiled by Homebrew
[...]
$ vim --version | grep ruby
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +wildmenu
Linking: clang -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.4 -mmacosx-version-min=10.15 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.32.1_1/lib/perl5/5.32.1/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin -lpython3.9 -framework CoreFoundation -lruby.3.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.0_1/lib
$ which -a ruby
/Users/username/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.6.5 (set by /Users/username/.rbenv/version)
```

Comment: See `:help if-ruby`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this depends on Vim build configuration. `:ver` output may indicate the following:

- `-lang` interface for "lang" wasn't compiled at all;
- `+lang` everything was statically linked into Vim executable;
- `+lang/dyn` interface was linked against dynamic library (dll/so)

If it's linked dynamically then the library will be searched and loaded on demand by option value (e.g. `:h 'rubydll'`). In this case it may point to any installation you want. (Although `-DRUBY_VERSION=XX` specified at compile-time may still be relevant and Vim may fail to load mismatched library).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  In my case, I see `+ruby`, meaning it was statically linked.  Does this have any bearing on using Ruby gems in a `:ruby` command?  It's not clear to me how a gem would be loaded in this scenario.

Comment: @BenjaminOakes Well, it's you who programs in Ruby, not me. So you should probably know how to setup all the things yourself. The only (obvious) point is that all Ruby commands must be executed from within Vim, as you can't run buitin interpreter from the command-line. But you should really consider to install another Vim build. At the very least, managing one ruby installation is easier than two.

Comment: Makes sense.  I'll consider this further.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your platform, or how you installed Vim. If we're talking about default behavior, these things matter.

Unless you statically compiled Ruby into Vim, it will be whichever Ruby is first in your PATH, or first in *fish_user_paths* if you use the fish shell. On macOS and typical desktop Linux distributions like Ubuntu, that's what you should expect out of the box.

Other ways to check include:

1. Using `which -a ruby` will show you all the rubies in your *PATH*.

   If Ruby 3.0.0 is not the first item listed, or not the version installed to /usr/bin/ruby, then you can be pretty sure that something else  is managing it.
2. Check `env | fgrep -i ruby` for settings from various Ruby managers.

   Version managers usually work by modifying your environment. For example, chruby adds *CHRUBY_VERSION* to the environment, and *RUBY_ROOT* to set the path for the selected Ruby. Other common version managers will also update the environment in various ways, so this is a good place to look.
3. Check your shell initialization files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

   If you aren't setting up RVM, rbenv, or chruby in your shell's initialization script, then you probably aren't using one of them. Of course, that doesn't preclude the use of symlinks, GNU stow, or other redirections, but if you didn't set them up and aren't working on a multiuser system where someone else may have, then you can be pretty confident that invoking `ruby` is calling the Ruby that's first in your *PATH*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I installed `vim` using `brew` on macOS 10.15.7.  I have added more details to the body of my question.

I don't think it's using Ruby in my `PATH` based on @Matt's answer.  As far as I can tell based on the checks you provided, I have not installed Ruby 3.0 *except* in `vim`.  From what I currently know, it is likely statically compiled.  In that case, is it possible to `require` Ruby gems from within `vim`?

Comment: @BenjaminOakes The current bottled version installed by `brew install vim` is v8.2.2800 and is compiled with `+ruby/dyn`, so it should be using your PATH. If you made changes to the way it's being installed, or recompiled it to use a static version, then you'll have to recompile. Gems are dynamic, so using a static Ruby is going to cause you problems. While there may be a plugin that supports Bundler or gem commands from inside Vim, it certainly isn't natively supported by Vim itself other than running `:gem install foo` or similar.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll consider options for rebuilding.